# Efficient way to determine number of logged in users in a database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Our MySQL database has a `users` table with a `logged_in, BOOL` column which is set when a user is detected to log in or out.

On our website we would display "users logged in to application", but I'm wary of simply doing `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE logged_in = 1` for performance reasons.

We expect the users table might have a few thousand rows, but only a handful (say 20) of users would be logged in at any time.

Is there a way to make sure this query can be optimized in MySQL, perhaps involving a KEY or a VIEW? Or do I need to create an auxillary table like `logged_in_users` along-side users and update this as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If there is an index on `logged_in` it should be a very fast query since the number of those being logged in will be pretty small comapred to the whole user table (a logged_in = 0 might not be very efficient however :) )  This is one of those cases where an index on a column with only 2 possible values can make for super efficient queries for one of the values.
2. Don't do a `count(*)`, do a `count(your_primary_key)`.  That way if you have logged_in indexed, the entire query is covered for optimal performance.

Comment: "a logged_in = 0 might not be very efficient however" - can you clarify what you mean, or if there'sa  better way?